# Solving IBVP with Laplace Transform

Tags: partial-differential-equations, problem-solving, laplace-transform, boundary-value-problem, initial-value-problems

It is given the following BVP
\begin{align}
u_{t} &= u_{xxxx},\quad\quad x \in (0, \pi), t >0 \tag1\\
u(0,t) &= u(\pi,t) = 0 ,\quad t > 0 \tag 2\\
u_{x}(0,t) &= e^{-4t},\quad t > 0 \tag3\\
u_{x}(\pi,t) &= -\cosh(\pi) \cdot e^{-4t}, t > 0 \ \tag4
\end{align}

and initial condition:

$u(x,0) = \sin(x)\cosh(x), x \in (0, \pi)$

Furthermore, $u$ is bounded as $t \to \infty$.

The Laplace transformed IBVP with initials condition is
$$s \bar{u}-\bar{u}_{xxxx}-u(x,0)=0 $$
This is essentially an "ODE" (Fourth order, linear) in form
$$\bar{u}^{(4)}-s \bar{u}+\sin(x)\cosh(x)=0$$
Now we are trying to solve the IBVP with the boundary conditions
\begin{align}
\bar{u}(0,s)&=0=\bar{u}(\pi ,s)\\
\bar{u}_{x}(0,s)&=\frac{1}{s+4}\\
\bar{u}_{x}(\pi ,s)&=-\frac{\cosh (\pi )}{s+4} 
\end{align}

However, I can not find the general solution and apply the inverse transform.

Comment: $$u = (\sin x \cosh x) e^{-4t}$$ seems to do the trick.

Comment: See [IBVP with laplace transform](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4646306/u-t-u-xxxx-ibvp-with-laplace-transform)

Comment: @MatthewCassell what kind of trick? the undetermined coefficients?

Comment: Just by inspection.